# Lineage OS changelog in update screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lineageos

If I recall correctly, with Cyanogenmod from the update screen I could click on a future download and see the change log. Is there anyway to restore that behavior with Lineage OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a change-log for LineageOS, and it's prime on their download screen you can see it at https://download.lineageos.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that changelog list on cyanogenmod update screen but it sounds like a nice feature.

There is at least one [webpage with changelog](https://www.cmxlog.com/14.1/) and there was a [changelog app](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=changelog&fdid=org.polaric.cyanogenmodchangelog) (no longer working with lineageos).However a new app is there for [lineage changelog.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vasudevrb.cmchangelog&hl=en) Maybe that does help.